# Pausing at positing in GRBL while holding motor current

Tags: python, cnc

I'm trying to get grbl to move the carriage of my 2D scanner to a specific position, pause there for a certain amount of time (until the sensor does its thing), and then proceed to the next position which I want to scan.

The scanner is a simple DIY using an arduino uno and the CNC shield. Motion is cartesian, with 2 motors (& drivers) running the y-axis, and one the x-axis. Nothing fancy to see here.

Scenarios I tried so far:

1. Using `G1`: I can never get it to pause at the position I want to scan
2. Using `G0`: I do get it to pause there, but it drops motor current, losing a step and making precise scanning impossible.

Any ideas how I could fix either scenario, or a new approach all together?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.Robotics. You might need to edit your question and provide a schematic, and/or your code in full (or at least the relevant part of the code). Is the scanner a commercial scanner or a DIY?

Comment: good idea. I gave a tiny bit more detail on the scanner, but this is mostly a software/grbl related question.

Comment: The more information the better (w.r.t. code and schematic). It will help people understand the issue, maybe see errors that you've over looked and also it enables people to try to reproduce the issue for themselves, in order to come up with a good solution. :-)